# Convert XLSX to CSV correctly using python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv

I am looking for a python library or any help to convert .XLSX files to .CSV files.

Comment: Another option is using pandas: ```df = pd.read_excel("./data.xlsx")``` and then
```df.to_csv("./data.csv", sep=",")```

Comment: Pandas actually uses `xlrd` under the hood.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Read your excel using the `xlrd` module and then you can use the `csv` module to create your own csv.

Install the xlrd module in your command line:

`pip install xlrd`

Python script:

```
import xlrd
import csv

def csv_from_excel():
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('excel.xlsx')
    sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    your_csv_file = open('your_csv_file.csv', 'w')
    wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

    your_csv_file.close()

# runs the csv_from_excel function:
csv_from_excel()
```

Comment: at least use xlsx in your example(sort of yours at least it looks like it came from elsewhere :P) since thats what was asked :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley this is not my answer. It came from the stackoverflow only. I tried to paste the hyperlink but somehow it was not coming in my comment. if for some reason I've violated any rule or policy of forum I'm really sorry for that.

Comment: Sometimes if the excel contains unicode characters you may need to specify the encoding, when creating/openning the destination file.

Comment: Is there any way of keeping the date format without it being converted to a date number format e.g. 43448

Comment: this solution no longer works. xlrd cannot handle xlsx anymore.

Comment: [pandas library] (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-excel-to-csv-in-python/)  can convert xlsx to csv