# Python, xlrd can i convert xlsx to csv file without knowing the worksheet name?

Tags: excel, csv, python-3.x, xlrd

i was looking at the example here: [Convert XLSX to CSV correctly using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105118/convert-xlsx-to-csv-correctly-using-python)

but the files i will import might have diverse worksheet names. can i do it without knowing the name or import it somehow?

Comment: You can use 'nsheets' attribute to know the number of sheets in the book and the 'sheet_by_index()' method to get the sheet object to work with it.

Comment: `sheet_by_index(0)` to get the first sheet of the excel book.