# Is the data in xlsx cells string?

Tags: python, scrapy, xlsx

Am using [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105118/convert-xlsx-to-csv-correctly-using-python) and doing

`if sheet.row_values(rownum)[0] is not 'Value':`
   ....`print sheet.row_values(rownum)[0]`

After I do that, I still get `Value` printed. Could it be that the `sheet.row_values(rownum)[0]` value is not a string? Or why is the `If` statement not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is` is testing the identity of an object.

if I am to write:

```
a = 1
b = 1

a is b # not guaranteed to be true
```

This is because the variable itself may point at different data, which is your case.

Using the `==` equality operator would give you the desired results, because it would actually look at the contents, not the strings identifier.

***Note*** when you are comparing a variable to `None`, the `is` operator is okay, because there is actually only ever one `None` object.