# Python Open XML and Save to CSV

Tags: xml, excel, python-3.x, csv, subprocess

I need to open an XML file and save it as a CSV.
I am not interested in extracting contents (i.e. via lmtree). 
I just want Python to do what I would normally do (open the XML file in Excel and save as a CSV file).

I know this can work to open the XML file in Excel:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("%s %s" % (application_path, filepath))
```

...but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Thanks in advance!

**Updates:**

1. Here's a sample file (it's an XML Spreadsheet file, if that helps):
   https://drive.google.com/open?id=193ML_2r5i56cEhydm1wYFQtXJCgRA3r_
2. No need for Python to enable editing. I just had to read this:

   https://www.thrivenetworks.com/blog/turn-off-enable-editing-office-2010/

Comment: If the XML file is a .xlsx check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105118/convert-xlsx-to-csv-correctly-using-python

Comment: I wish it were. Unfortunately, it's .xml.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library already built for this called `xmlutils`.

1. Run `pip install xmlutils` to install
2. `xml2csv --input "samples/fruits.xml" --output "samples/fruits.csv" --tag "item"` to convert to CSV

<sub>See [this site](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmlutils/1.1) or [the documentation](http://nadh.in/code/xmlutils.py) for more details.</sub>

Comment: Didn't work. I think the structure of the XML was is too complex.

Comment: Hmm, that's too bad.  Did it give you an error?  And would you mind putting down the command you used specifically?

Comment: Oh, also, this was built in Python 2.7 I believe -- are you using Python 3?

Comment: Yes, Sorry, I'll update the tags. I just substituted the XML and  CSV file names with the path\names to my file and desired output. This was the error: AttributeError: 'IterParseIterator' object has no attribute 'next'

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
pip install pyautogui

files=glob.glob(pathin+"*.xml")

def lazysave(inputs):
    print("%s" % (inputs))
        #subprocess.Popen("%s %s" % (path, file),shell=True)
    subprocess.Popen(inputs,shell=True)
    time.sleep(3)
    pag.FAILSAFE = True
    pag.keyDown('ctrlleft');pag.press('s');pag.keyUp('ctrlleft') #save file
    pag.PAUSE = 1
    pag.press('right') #go to "No - do not keep same format"
    #pag.PAUSE = .5
    pag.press('enter') #select "No - do not keep same format"
    #pag.PAUSE = 2
    pag.press('tab') #go to filetype dropdown menu
    #pag.PAUSE = 2
    pag.press('down') #activate filetype dropdown menu
    #pag.PAUSE = 2
    pag.press('down');pag.press('down') #go to CSV filetype
    #pag.PAUSE = .5
    pag.press('enter') #select CSV filetype
    #pag.PAUSE = .5
    pag.press('enter') #select "SAVE" button
    #pag.PAUSE = .5
    pag.press('enter') #select "Yes" button to keep CSV format
    #pag.PAUSE = .5
    pag.keyDown('altleft');pag.press('f4');pag.keyUp('alt') #close file
    pag.PAUSE = .5
    pag.press('right') #go to do not save (already saved)
    #pag.PAUSE = .5
    pag.press('enter') #select do not save (already saved)

for f in files:
     inputs=[path,f]
     lazysave(inputs)
```