# Convert hex addresses .xlsx file to csv int using python

Tags: python, excel, csv, hex, export-to-csv

Given a .xlsx file i want to convert it to .csv with the following format using Python

Given hex addresses .xlsx :

```
0xbfb22b18
0xbfb22b14
0xbfb22b10
0xbfb22b0c
0xbfb22b18
0xbfb22b14
0xbfb22b10
0xbfb22b0c
```

I need to convert to int .scv and add at the first line row the word "train_data"

```
train_data
3216124696
3216124692
3216124688
3216124684
3216124696
3216124692
3216124688
3216124684
```

The only relative I found is using [panda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105118/convert-xlsx-to-csv-correctly-using-python) , but I don't know how I can add the "train_data" .

Answer (score 0):

How about

```py
data = open('tmp.xlsx', 'r').read()

numbers = map(lambda x: str(int(x, 16)), data.split())

content = 'train_data\n' + '\n'.join(numbers) + '\n'

with open('tmp.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You go:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', index_col=None, names=['train_data'])
df['train_data'] = df['train_data'].apply(lambda x: int(x, 16))
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```